# XHR.send(file + params)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to figure out how to send a file and paramaters within the same XMLHttpRequest. Is this possible?

Obviously I can do xhr.send(file+params) or xhr.(file,params). And I don't think I can set two different request headers to do this...

```
xhr.setRequestHead('X_FILENAME', file.name)
xhr.send(file);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(params);
```

Is there some way to send the params without having to use GET, or a secondary xhr request?

Comment: you may have to use FormData https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

Comment: Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602021/submitting-a-html-form-with-ajax-that-includes-a-file-input and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: @ Charles: How are you sending a file via XHR? Did you read it client-side via the File API, or...? (It matters, because if you read it client-side via the File API, then it's just another parameter...)

Answer (score 12):

If you rely on browser which supports `FormData`, you can use the code below (JavaScript):

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('param1', 'myParam');
formData.append('param2', 12345); 
formData.append('uploadDir', 'public-data');  
formData.append('myfile', file);

xhr.send(formData);
```

Then, on your server side you can have access to your variables by using this code (PHP):

```
<?
  $param1 = $_POST['param1']; //myParam
  $param2 = $_POST['param2']; //12345
  $uploaddir = $_POST['uploadDir']; //public-data
  $fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
  $fileZise = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
  $uploaddir = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$uploaddir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($fileName);       
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
  echo $fileName.' ['.$fileZise.'] was uploaded successfully!';
?>
```

To get all parameters of `$_FILES['myfile']`, use `var_dump($_FILES["myfile"])`

Answer (score 6):

> Is there some way to send the params without having to use GET, or a secondary xhr request?

Yes, you can encode them into the URL (just like `GET`), even though you're doing a `POST`. E.g.:

```
xhr.open(yourUrl + "?foo=" + encodeURIComponent(foo) + "&bar=" + encodeURIComponent(bar));
// ...
xhr.send(file);
```

I'm assuming in the above that you must know something about sending a file via XHR that I don't know. :-)

---

Assuming that `file` is the actual *content* of the file, read via the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), then isn't it just another parameter? So:

```
xhr.send(
    "filedata=" + encodeURIComponent(file) +
    "&foo=" + encodeURIComponent(foo) +
    "&bar=" + encodeURIComponent(bar)
);
```

Comment: that's kinda what I meant by using GET... I didn't want to append them to the URL.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: Well, it's **not** using `GET`. You're still using `POST`, you're just passing data in two places, which is perfectly normal. If you don't want to send data in the URL, say that, not that you don't want to use `GET`. Those are different statements.

Comment: hmm... would I still access the variables via $_POST server-side? If that's the case then it may be valid. I try and avoid $_GET as it's easier to manipulate the information.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: I'm not a big PHP-head, but I suspect you probably still access them via `$_GET`. But both [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) are associative arrays of the parameters received (in the relevant part of the request), what makes the associative array in `$_POST` easier to use than the one in `$_GET`?

Comment: I didn't say it was easier to use, it's just not as easy for the user to manipulate the variables

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: Ah, I understand that sentence now. Quite true, although of course, you can't trust *anything* the client sends you. :-)

Comment: Its always secure and better to submit forms using $POST.

Comment: @Codex - POST isn't remotely more secure than GET. But if the call is supposed to change state, POST is the more appropriate choice, since GET is supposed to be idempotent.